# Time picker in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I have 2 field to show the date and time,in one field date is showing correctly by using NSDateFormatter and in another field want to show a time in UIPicker programmatically and put it into the label.
Help me in this

Comment: You can use: https://github.com/Krishnarajsalim/KRTimePicker-iOS

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `UIDatePicker` with `Time` mode

```
self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 180.0f); // set frame as your need
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
[self.view addSubview: self.datePicker];
```

And set selected time in `UILabel` such like

```
UILabel  * label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 70, 300, 50)];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];    
label1.text = currentTime;
[self.view addSubview:label1];
```

**Edited:**

Add following code to datePicker

```
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And call this method

```
- (void)dateChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date]; 
    NSLog(@"%@", currentTime);
}
```

Comment: @hussainShabbir - what do you mean ??

Comment: @iPatel thanks buddy it showing the time but current time only,i want to set a any time

Comment: @ipatel,Sorry by mistake i typed comments on your code;)